# Codeception - Laravel 4 - All functional tests fail since running composer update

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, functional-testing, codeception

I have a Laravel 4 application running on my development machine *(MacBook Pro, 15-inch, Mid 2010)* under a Homestead environment.

Since starting the project more than a year ago, I have used test driven development with Codeception as the key principle of my workflow.
My workflow is based upon that presented by Jeffrey Way in his ['Build Larabook From Scratch'](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch) series on Laracasts.

I have three test suites: functional, integration and unit.
Both my integration and unit tests are still working completely fine.

However, since running **composer self-update** and **composer update** yesterday when attempting to install 'DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 4' *("barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*")*, my functional tests have randomly stopped working, with every single test yielding 'Error' instead of 'Pass' or 'Fail'.

I immediately removed this dependancy yet the tests continue to result in 'Error'.

I have tried checking out previous git commits and running the tests however the same errors arise. **All tests must pass before a git commit is made** so I see no reason why this would not have worked.

I have also tried removing codeception and all tests completely, reinstalling codeception and then copying over a few tests. The same errors occured.

I have also tried explicitly specifying an older version of codeception in my composer.json file and using this instead of using "~2.0".

The application is working perfectly both in development and production, it is only the test suite that is not working. However, no further development can be done until the test suite is working.

---

All of my functional tests rely on signing in a user, apart from one which registers a user. This is done in the way demonstrated by Jeffrey Way in the online tutorial series I previously mentioned, with a sign in helper method being referenced at the beginning of each test.

This is because all controller actions other than those that facilitate logging in, etc. are protected by an authentication filter.

---

When running *vendor/bin/codecept run functional --debug -vvv* the output for each test is as follows:

```
8) Failed to login to an account in Sessions/SignInCept (tests/functional/Sessions/SignInCept.php)

[ErrorException] Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/insightsa/app/views/pages/home.blade.php)

Scenario Steps:

2. $I->signIn() at tests/functional/Sessions/SignInCept.php:7
1. // As an an Insight member 

#1  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php:41
#2  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php:56
#3  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:134
#4  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:102
#5  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:76
#6  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php:43
#7  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php:202
#8  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1501
#9  /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1036
#10 /home/vagrant/insightsa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1001
```

The test that I have used as an example above, *SignInCept.php*, is as follows:

```
<?php

$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('an Insight member');
$I->wantTo('login to an account');

$I->signIn();

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');
$I->see('Login successful.');

$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());
```

The *signIn* function is referenced from a FunctionalHelper class:

```
class FunctionalHelper extends \Codeception\Module {

/**
 * @throws \Codeception\Exception\Module
 */
public function signIn()
{
    $I = $this->getModule('Laravel4');

    $password = "test";
    $user = $this->haveAnAccount(compact('password'));

    $I->amOnPage('/login');
    $I->fillField('email', $user->email);
    $I->fillField('password', $password);
    $I->click('Sign In');
}

/**
 * @param $model
 * @param array $overrides
 * @return mixed
 */
public function have($model, $overrides = [])
{
    return TestDummy::create($model, $overrides);
}

/**
 * @param array $overrides
 * @return mixed
 */
public function haveAnAccount($overrides = [])
{
    return $this->have('Insight\Users\User', $overrides);
}
```

**...**

---

On logging a user in, a controller renders the view *home.blade.php*.
The only variable that this view makes use of is *$currentUser* like so:

```
{{ $currentUser->username }}
```

and also like so:

```
@if($currentUser->email == "user@example.com")
...
@endif
```

This variable is exposed to the view via the BaseController that all other controllers extend:

```
protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }

        View::share('currentUser', Auth::user());
    }
```

---

My *functional.suite.yml* file is as follows:

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# suite for functional (integration) tests.
# emulate web requests and make application process them.
# Include one of framework modules (Symfony2, Yii2, Laravel4) to use it.

class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled: [Filesystem, FunctionalHelper, Laravel4, Asserts, Db]
```

---

Any help would be very much appreciated as I cannot continue to work for my client on this project until I get this sorted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is home.blade.php?

Comment: The view rendered by the controller action that is redirected to after a user logs in. This controller is protected by an authentication filter.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Please post the contents of home.blade.php

Comment: Home.blade.php is all static content other than that use of the variables shown in the question.

Comment: However, when I am home I will post the contents of the file on here for you.

Comment: If the problem came after running `composer update` I would try reverting to a previous version of your composer.lock file(if possible), deleting your vendor directory, and running `composer install`

Comment: I've tried that to no avail, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I have now decided to rewrite my test suite using behat and mink which works perfectly. It will take a couple of days to rewrite all the tests however I am finding I actually prefer the way in which you define the business' needs in Behat.